# How to run WebRTC library

Tags: webrtc, voice-detection

I would like to use this library: https://github.com/voixen/voixen-vad

They offer some example code at the bottom of the readme. 
My question is how do I run it?
What kind of project do I need to create to integrate this library and run the said code?

Any help or example would be fantastic.

Comment: It's a Node.js (javascript project). In case you're interested in a Python version of the same thing, see https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad